# Cycle through filenames in vim

Tags: beginner, linux, vimscript

So I have a list of files which names are something like this

```
long_boring_filename_del_1.tex
long_boring_filename_del_2.tex
long_boring_filename_del_3.sty
long_boring_filename_del_4.tex
```

I want to cycle through these filenames using some mapping defined in vim. Meaning if I have `long_boring_filename_del_2.tex` open and hit the mapping it should take me to the next file `long_boring_filename_del_3.sty`. It should also loop, meaning `long_boring_filename_del_4.tex` should take me back to `long_boring_filename_del_4.tex`.

*In addition I want to be able to cycle thorugh the files in both directions.*

After obtaining a bit of [help over at vi and vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20259/cycle-between-filenames) I was able to come up with the following solution (which works).

```
function! s:next_del()

    " do nothing if current filename doesn't match "
    if @% !~# 'del-\v[1234]\.'
        return
    endif

    " open next file "
    let fnameA = substitute(@%, '\v[1234]\ze\.', '\=submatch(0)%4+1', '')
    if filereadable(fnameA)
        exec 'echo'
        exec 'e ' . fnameA
    else 
        " if the .tex file does not exist check if the .sty versions does "
        let fnameB = substitute(fnameA, '\.tex', '\.sty', '')
        if filereadable(fnameB)
            exec 'e ' . fnameB
        else 
            " if the above fails, check if changing sty to tex works "
            let fnameB = substitute(fnameA, '\.sty', '\.tex', '')
            if filereadable(fnameB)
                exec 'e ' . fnameB
            endif
        endif
    endif
endfunction

" Same as s:next_del() except this cycles in the opposite direction "
function! s:prev_del()

    " do nothing if current filename doesn't match "
    if @% !~# 'del-\v[1234]\.'
        return
    endif

    " open previous file "
    let fnameA = substitute(@%, '\v[1234]\ze\.', '\=submatch(0)-1', '')
    let fnameA = substitute(fnameA, '\v[0]\ze\.', '\=submatch(0)+4', '')
    if filereadable(fnameA)
        exec 'e ' . fnameA
    else 
        " if the .tex file does not exist check if the .sty versions does "
        let fnameB = substitute(fnameA, '\.tex', '\.sty', '')
        if filereadable(fnameB)
            exec 'e ' . fnameB
        else
            " if the above fails, check if changing sty to tex works "
            let fnameB = substitute(fnameA, '\.sty', '\.tex', '')
            if filereadable(fnameB)
                exec 'e ' . fnameB
            endif
        endif
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <localleader>w :call <sid>next_del()<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <localleader>q :call <sid>prev_del()<CR>
```

While it work I would love to get some pointers on how to improve the code as I am very much a beginner when it come to `vimscript`. Here are the major points in the code that needs improvement:

- Can the two functions `s:next_del()` and `s:prev_del()` be combined into one?
- My method of cycling backwards is very barbaric.

  ```
  let fnameA = substitute(@%, '\v[1234]\ze\.', '\=submatch(0)-1', '')
  let fnameA = substitute(fnameA, '\v[0]\ze\.', '\=submatch(0)+4', '')
  ```

  I did it in this fashion because apparently you  can't separate the 
  leading \ and = , as otherwise it's a pure string. I would like to get some pointers on how to improve it.
- Lastly my method of "checking" whether I have a `sty` file or `tex` file is strange at best. I do not really check, just change `sty` to `tex` and see if it works. I tried to get some `regex` going by using `(tex|sty)` but for some reason vimscript did not accept it. I would like to learn a better method of alternating between the `sty` and `tex` files.

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be improved in many aspects, so it is easier to write my own solution rather to rewrite your.

**Differences from your:**

1. I suggest to use `glob()` function to find all files, which are matching to a pattern.
2. Singular `Move(move_direction)` function is enough, a duplication is not needed.
3. Not only new files are opened, but switching between already opened buffers are supported.

---

```
function! s:MyCompare(i1, i2)
    let l:f = str2nr(matchstr(a:i1, '[0-9]\+'))
    let l:s = str2nr(matchstr(a:i2, '[0-9]\+'))
    return l:f == l:s ? 0 : l:f > l:s ? 1 : -1
endfunc

function! s:Move(step)
    let l:current_filename = bufname('%')
    let l:common_part = matchstr(l:current_filename, '[^0-9]*')

    "" sort() is needed for numerical order
    let l:matched_file_list = sort(glob(l:common_part . '*', 0, 1), 's:MyCompare') 

    let l:list_size = len(l:matched_file_list)
    let l:cur_idx = index(l:matched_file_list, l:current_filename)

    let l:next_idx = (l:cur_idx + a:step) % l:list_size
    let l:next_buf_name = l:matched_file_list[l:next_idx]

    if !bufloaded(l:next_buf_name)
        execute 'e' l:next_buf_name
    endif

    execute 'buffer' l:next_buf_name
endfunction

command! Fwrd call s:Move(1)
command! Bwrd call s:Move(-1)

noremap <Leader>c :Fwrd<CR>
noremap <Leader>d :Bwrd<CR>
```

**Directory content**

```
ls -1

long_boring_filename_del_101.tex
long_boring_filename_del_1.tex
long_boring_filename_del_202.tex
long_boring_filename_del_2.tex
long_boring_filename_del_3.sty
long_boring_filename_del_4.tex
long_boring_filename_del_5.tex
```

**Demonstration**

<kbd>,</kbd> is a Leader key.

[image]